# joint probability distribution function to find P(X+Y<1)

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

The question is to find $P(X+Y\leq1)$ given a joint probability distribution function of $f(x,y)=10xy^2{I}_{(0<x<y<1)}$.

My attempt is

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{1-y}10xy^2I_{(0<x<y<1)}dxdy=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\min(1-y,y)}10xy^2dxdy=\int_{0}^{1}5{(\min(1-y,y))}^2y^2dy=\frac{1}{32}+\frac{1}{12}=\frac{11}{96}$

Then I tried calculating $P(X+Y\geq1)$ in the similar way, expecting the sum of $P(X+Y\leq1)$ and $P(X+Y\geq1)$ would be $1$. However, it gave the result of

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{1-y}^{\infty}10xy^2I_{(0<x<y<1)}dxdy=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{\max(1-y,0)}^{y}10xy^2dxdy=\int_{0}^{1}5[y^2-{(\max(1-y,y))}^2]y^2dy=-\frac{5}{96}+\frac{85}{96}=\frac{5}{6}$

which seemed definitely wrong. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to integrate over a triangle

[image]

$$\mathbb{P}(X+Y<1)=\int_0^{0.5}10x\left[\int_x^{1-x}y^2dy\right]dx=\frac{11}{96}$$

---

Calculating the complement, as you tried, I find

$$\mathbb{P}(X+Y>1)=\int_{0.5}^{1}5y^2\left[\int_{1-y}^{y}2xdx \right]dy=\dots =\frac{85}{96}$$

Comment: 1. Why is $10x$ located outside of the integration in $dy$?
2. Is my way of obtaining the same result as yours just a coincidence? (for P(X+Y<1))

Comment: @hmje : it's outside the integration in $dy$ but inside the integration in $dx$

Comment: I've edited the comment, apologies for not being used to the platform

Comment: @hmje : If you look at my edits I calculated also the complement probability and all is good...